# Duplicate declaration in the current scope error; two loops with the same variable, variable scope

Tags: vba, excel, scope

I have this code: there are two `for` loops from `1` to `10` in it. In each loop a variable `k` is declared.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim k As Long
        k = i * 2

        Debug.Print k
    Next


    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 10
        Dim k As Long  'error here
        k = j * 2

        Debug.Print k
    Next

End Sub
```

However when I try to run it I get a `duplicate declaration in the current scope` error. I'm not sure why I get it - **isn't a variable's scope limited by the loop, since it was declared within it**? Is there any way to remove the remnants of the first variable so that it would be possible to create a variable with the same name in the second loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a variable in a procedure, this variable is valid for all the procedure, not only for the `loops`.
If you want to clear your variable, you can set `k = 0`

When a local variable is declared with the Dim statement, the variable remains in existence only as long as the procedure in which it is declared is running. Usually, when the procedure is finished running, the values of the procedure's local variables are not preserved, and the memory allocated to those variables is released. The next time the procedure is executed, all of its local variables are reinitialized.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Comment: Please do not quote links. They are not quotes.

Comment: It does not make sense to declare your variable `k` within the `for loop` because everytime it starts the loop `k` **is declare again and again and again**.

So I highly recomend you to declare your variable `k` outside the `for loop`

Comment: @Moreno In a generic programming language it DOES make sense, since you may not want to risk using the previous value for that variable.